# Where can I find the GitHub site for Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking to create a responsive site and would like to use Bootstrap. I noticed that there was talk about bootstrap 4 but then I have not seen any mention of it since last year.

Can anyone who is familar with the release cycle please tell me where I can find out information on Bootstrap 4. Is there a GitHub site for it?

Comment: I think the only people that might no are in the community here. That's why I posted to try and find out more.The github given does not even mention 4 as a milestone so I am wonder if this will be vaporware and not actually happen.

Comment: If you want to look at the release cycle, I suggest visiting the official twbs repository, and reading the commit history/changelog. However, FWIW, you _can_ implement Bootstrap on a Github Page -- it is no different than a "regular" site. GH Pages are just websites hosted (for free) by Github, taking HTML/CSS.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official releases page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases), the latest version is 3.3.5, released June 16, a little over a month ago.

There has been some chatter about a Bootstrap 4 alpha, and a mention on the [official blog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/), but no code has been released.

Comment: I checked the blog and the entry is for 29 Oct 2014 saying the first alpha will be in a couple of weeks.  Do you have any ideas if there will even be a version 4.  Has development of bootstrap slowed down to just updates?

Comment: @SamanthaJ That's the last public update. Your guess is as good as mine, although I would hardly call bootstrap development "slow". You could consider contacting the maintainers directly or opening an issue requesting a status update.

Comment: Thanks.  I see a lot of work going on with bootstrap but really confused as to why the very last mention of v4 is October and then as far as I can see there's complete silence.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find some information about Bootstrap v4 on multiple official bootstrap sources:

- the github repository, where contributors answer some people questions like here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16275
- the twitter page: https://twitter.com/getbootstrap (alpha 1 should be released this month!)
- the blog: http://blog.getbootstrap.com

I think the bootstrap v4 repository will be open for public when alpha 1 will be released. No official date for the moment except "later this month": https://twitter.com/mdo/status/630999238734819328